# False? error when using a MutiBinding Converter that is both an IMultiValueConverter and a MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Whenever I attempt to use an `IMultiValueConverter` that is also a `MarkupExtension` in XAML, I see the following error message in the Error List window:

> Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified

Despite the fact that this is displayed with the red-X error icon, the application still builds and runs fine, and as far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the code. Here a shortish snippet that is sufficient to trigger it:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Markup;

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(TestConverter))]
    // using typeof(IMultiValueConverter) doesn't help
    public class TestConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new[] {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue};
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.TestPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Title="TestPage">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <!-- Next 4 lines are underlined in blue with the message shown -->
                <MultiBinding Converter="{local:TestConverter}">
                    <Binding />
                    <Binding />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Am I missing something here (an attribute?) or is this a bug in the VS parser?

Comment: Use your converter as a static resource.

Comment: @Abin Doing that *and* not implementing `IMarkupExtension` will silence the error, but I'd really rather not lose the convenience.

Comment: I tested the sample you provided in VS2013 and VS2015, worked in both for me without the error message. Strange... that error should only be shown if you completely omit the "Converter=" part in your XAML.

Comment: @Szabolcs That is strange, and unfortunately means it's going to be a lot harder to figure out. Just in case this is the reason it works for you, it appears I only see the error when I actually have the XAML document open for editing.